# Rails command not found in net-ssh remote server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssh

I am having trouble when running Rails command from a remote server using the [net-ssh](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh) gem, which is mean to execute commands to remote servers and get capture th## Heading ##eir input.

Here is an example of it working proper (without running Rails):

```
# remote server
irb
2.3.7 :001 > require 'net/ssh'
 => true 
2.3.7 :002 > 
2.3.7 :003 >   @hostname = "XX.XX.XXX.XXX"
 => "XX.XX.XXX.XXX" 
2.3.7 :004 > @username = "ubuntu"
 => "ubuntu" 
2.3.7 :005 > ssh = Net::SSH.start(@hostname, @username, :keys => "/home/user/Documents/aws_key.pem")
2.3.7 :006 > puts ssh.exec!("ls")

bin
cdrom
etc
sys
usr
var
proc
```

Clearly, at this point, my success to the other server is visible. I am connected and I can run `ls` and it returs to me exactly what is there.

Here is where I am having issues, specifically when I run the Rails command.

```
puts ssh.exec!('cd /home/user/app && bin/rails runner "puts User.last.id"')
bash: rails: command not found
```

I have rails installed on the server I ssh into. My question is how do I run rails commands using net-ssh gem?

Comment: Does the command work if you ssh in and run it? I'm wondering if the environment is somehow different...

Comment: You could also try without using Ruby such as `ssh user@hostname "cd /home/user/app && bin/rails --version"`

Comment: @kris, Yes. If I run `rails -v` it will spit out `5.2.0`, however... the case is not the same on the other server when I `ssh`.

Comment: @Kris, so when I run that command, I actually get a different output. `/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in 'require':cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)`

Comment: @dsomel21 What do you get for `puts ssh.exec!('cd /home/user/app && ls')` and `puts ssh.exec!('cd /home/user/app/bin && ls')`? Is it showing you the contents of your app directory, and is it finding `rails` in `bin`?